# Android: Can I use google ClientLogin for user registration?

Tags: android, authentication, client

We are developing an app that has the option of user registration. Now we want to make this process as easy as possible for the user (to encourage registration), so we basically want the user to login with his google account and our server will simply store his google username (not his password). We are not accessing any google services with the app, but simply want to give an easy option to register and login. Is this something that other apps are doing? Does Google have a problem with that?

Comment: ClientLogin requires a password. So, that's not advisable. OAuth again, requires the user to enter his username and password as well.

Have you considered using the AccountManager to get the users email for setting up your registration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really recommend you to use the AccountManager from Android you don't have any problems with storing the password on your severs if you use the Auth Token. And the biggest benefit is, that the user don't have to enter his email or password 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html

Look at the steps in the documentation

- Get all available accounts
- View them in a List
- Request a [Auth Token](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#getAuthToken%28android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.app.Activity,%20android.accounts.AccountManagerCallback%3Candroid.os.Bundle%3E,%20android.os.Handler%29)

Comment: Ok I'll definitely have a look at that. BTW is there a version of AccountManager for non-android environment? Let's say we want to have a site that allows login from different accounts?

Comment: if I understood you correctly :)
The AccountManager doesnt just store the google account, it stores multiple accounts. so if you i.e. have facebook, twitter, an exchange account, it's all stored in the Accountmanager. you also can make the registration on the phone you can create your own [account](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/index.html) which is pretty cool.

Comment: This could also be interesting  for you http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SLsfzTNIykY&feature=BFa&list=LL8vBS95NL2_s&index=24

Answer (score 0):

One more option would be to use some kind of unique ID, like Android_id or some other Id, which is unique for each device or installation. I guess, you just need to get hold of a unique ID for your app so that  our server can recognize from which installation the request is coming.